# Is it possible to show specific enum references in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When creating an enum, it typically looks like this in VS 2022:

[image: how it looks today]

Is there possibly a way of showing the references for each specific enum  like this:

[image: what i want]

I know i can exchange the enum for static string properties for example, but they are not constant and can not be used in switch cases. I also know about "find all references", but i want it to show directly like in the picture.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? Please update question and tags

Comment: Sorry, visual-studio 2022.

Comment: I think CodeLens does not currently supports references to specific enums, you can right-click and choose "Find All References" or press ctrl+K+R  or press Shift+F12 to find all references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that CodeLens currently supports references for specific enums.
An alternative handy way to find all the references is to mark the enum child and:
Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to find all references.